# OpenAI Python Package Error: 'ChatCompletion' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, openai-api, chatgpt-api

After updating my OpenAI package to version 1.1.1, I got this error when trying to read the ChatGPT API response:

> 'ChatCompletion' object is not subscriptable

Here is my code:

```py
messages = [
        {"role": "system", "content": '''You answer question about some service'''
        },
        {"role": "user", "content": 'The user question is ...'},
    ]
response = client.chat.completions.create(
        model=model,
        messages=messages,
        temperature=0
    )
response_message = response["choices"][0]["message"]["content"]
```

How can I resolve this error?

Comment: Did you refer the [release notes](https://pypi.org/project/openai/1.1.1/) `Module-level client` section, when updating the package version? I think it's pretty clear.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

In the latest OpenAI package the `response.choices` object type is changed and in this way you must read the response:

```
print(response.choices[0].message.content)
```

The complete working code:

```
from openai import OpenAI

client = OpenAI(api_key='YourKey')
GPT_MODEL = "gpt-4-1106-preview" #"gpt-3.5-turbo-1106"
messages = [
        {"role": "system", "content": 'You answer question about Web  services.'
        },
        {"role": "user", "content": 'the user message'},
    ]
response = client.chat.completions.create(
        model=model,
        messages=messages,
        temperature=0
    )
response_message = response.choices[0].message.content
print(response_message )
```

See [this example](https://github.com/openai/openai-python/blob/448ac7d046d12c26064b2050f3ce82bde3a24943/README.md?plain=1#L143) in the project README.

Comment: slight typo in the working code?  should be "model=GPT_MODEL" under the "response=..." 

"model=model" is an error